How to use an umd module in nuxt?
I have an umd module, which are several native vue components, embedding it in html and in vue, it is very easy, just make a script and then make a vue.component, the problem is that in nuxt, I don't know how I can do it
This is an example where everything works fine, in native html using vue:
First I load vue and the module in .umd format.
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="./dist/productsmodule.umd.js"></script>

In the script type=module:
<script type="module">
    const app = Vue.createApp();
    
    app.component('donproducts', productsmodule.productsIndex);
    app.component("v-select", productsmodule.vSelect);
    app.mount('#app');
</script>

Once all this is done, I can now use the component.
<donproducts
    token="example",
    apibaseurl="example",
    apiservicesurl="example",
    apiconnectionurl="example",
    origin="example",
    language="es",
    srcvirtualpath="/icons",
    integration="true",
  />

The problem is that I don't know how to do this in nuxt.

The comment from staging ground still applies. What exactly is this umd module? "U" stands for universal, means that it can be imported as CommonJS module. Did you try to import it? It's also unclear why it's in local dist/. If the components that are bundled to UMD belong to the same project, you're not supposed to import them from a bundle. Import them directly
